# How to create new EC2 instance in AutoScaling group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to create EC2 instance in autoscaling group. I want to do it manually using Ruby SDK. I haven't find any parameter to pass a name of AutoScaling Group name in [amazon-ec2 Docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/amazon-ec2/0.9.17/frames). Can anybody tell me that how to do it?

Comment: You need to create an autoscaling group first

Comment: frederick cheung. thanks. i have created a autoscaling group,but how to create EC2 instance in that group manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can't manually create an instance other than be updating the autoscaling group and increasing the desired number of instances by 1. Specific instances can be terminated with `TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup`.

You can also call `ExecutePolicy` to call a pre-existing autoscaling policy. I don't think you can trigger a cloud watch alarm from the API (other than by injecting sufficient amount of metric data to trigger the alarm (which you might not be able to do for non-custom metrics))

Comment: can we do it with triggering action on cloud watch using ruby/java api and create instace? But i haven't find how to trigger any event using ruby/java api in cloud watch.